# php session data inaccessible from lower folder

Tags: php, session

I am setting a session variable from .../folder/script.php
when i try to access it from .../script.php i get nothing

its probably something stupid but...can anyone explain? 
and yes i am starting the session. 
and i am using an overriden session if that helps any ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be setting a cookie with a path.

Try setting the cookie path to /,